# Selenium: Stability Issue while running multiple instances of chromedriver on one machine

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I am running multiple instances of google chrome via (chromedriver) on one machine using multi-threading. When I increase the instance count like 12+ (depending of the machine capacity) I start seeing the following issues

- Element is visible on the page but the wait command fails randomly even after waiting for long enough. It says the element is not present on the page. The same code always works if I reduce browser count (I also check the server performance issue, there is none)
- Click is performed on the element but the action is not triggered. (We can see the element color changed in the screenshot). In another forum, someone said that JS event binding to element is not completed.

I have two questions:

- Is it recommended a large number of instances of Google chrome via chromedriver on the machine?
- Is there any possible solution for the above problems

Thanks
Vinay

Comment: Hello it could be related to coding , can you add some code like how are you creating the web drivers instances .

Comment: Hi @Asmoun, I am using robotframework. Same thing is observed with a framework developed in Java too. I think it cant be a coding issue as it should not lead to flakiness.

Comment: have you tried to monitor your RAM ?  and other hardware resources while executing ? t

Comment: @Asmoun, nothing unusual was found. Both RAM and CPU were at least 30% empty all the time.

Answer (score 0):

1. First resize your window.
2. If you are using Headless browser then you should give a specific size to your browser.
3. Try to make own xpath and try to use xpaths instead of css selectors.It may prevent unable click or intercept.
4. Adjust everything in a proper manner of threading.
5. If CPU and RAM and everything is ok then try to look towards threading pool.

*And about your first questing:-*
**Yes you can definitely use multiple instances on windows machine.It have the capability . But you have to lookafter PORTS using a single instance.Or you can manually use debugger address and set ports like 9992**

Hope thease answer will help you definitely.